# Using the CKEditor whitelist plugin, how can I preserve/promote the child nodes of a disallowed tag?

Tags: ckeditor

The [whitelist plugin](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25504) for CKEditor adds sanitization rules to the dataProcessor dataFilter and htmlFilter. If an element is not in the whitelist, it is removed, along with any child nodes:

```
// console.log("Remove " + element.name);
// The element (as well as any content or children) is removed.
return false;
```

However, I want to preserve any content/children. Basically, I'd like this:

```
This is <u>really</u> important!
```

To become this:

```
This is really important!
```

NOT this:

```
This is important!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 37 of `whitelist/plugin.js`. Instead of returning `false`, what removes entire element, write:

`delete element.name;`

This will remove element's tags, but will leave the content.

Comment: This worked great. I had to remember to add a `if(typeof(element.name) != 'undefined') {}` around the following block that deals with attributes though. Just adding that here in case it will help anyone else.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that you can add early return or this condition. Or even better - cache element's name before deleting it and check with this name later in that function.